# 2 unresolved external symbols (C++ function basics)

Tags: c++

We learned about functions in class this week and I have narrowed my code down to 1 error which is "2 unresolved external symbols", last time I had this error was because I declared my functions within main but I made sure not to make the same mistake this time.

Also, when trying to run the program it says that

'File Name' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
I have turned on Not Using Precompiled Headers to no avail.

I have read numerous threads none of which helped, been working on this project for 7 hours now

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int getDivisor();
int calcSquare(int number);
void findNumbers(int divisor, int number, int square);


int main()
{
    int divisor = 0;
    int square = 0;
    int number = 0;

        cout << "Enter a divisor: ";
        cin >> divisor;
        cout << "Here are the numbers from 0 to 100 that are evenly 
divisible by " << divisor << ",\nand their squares:\n\n";

        square = pow(number, 2);
        for (int count = 0; ++count;)
        {
            if (count >= 0 && count <= 100, count % divisor == 0)
            {
                int calcSquare(number);
                cout << number << setw(6) << square << endl;

                return square;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: *"last time I had this error was because I declared my functions within main but I made sure not to make the same mistake this time."* Uh, I'm going to break the bad news - you still have functions defined inside `main`.

Comment: Not quite. He has useless function declarations in main, followed by blocks.

Comment: @Igor My teacher taught us to put the function definitions at the top of each block of code that is relevant to it, is this wrong?

Comment: @YungCoder A function definition looks like "return-type function-name(parameters) /*no semicolon!!*/ { statements }" and should NOT be inside another function definition like the one for `main`.

Comment: Either you misunderstood what your teacher said, or your teacher is incompetent.

Comment: Furthermore, If, as you claim you have "2 unresolved external symbols", then it is logically impossible for you to "run the program", since your compiler failed to produce an executable as a result of this error. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik And therefore "when **trying** to run the program", getting an error saying the name is not recognized as a command makes perfect sense.

Comment: @aschelper I thought that there was not supposed to be a semicolon but when I take them off I get errors asking me to put them back

Comment: @YungCoder That's because they're inside `main`, where another function definition is not allowed.

Comment: My teacher ALSO taught us to put the *function declaration* at the top of each block of code that is relevant to. Other languages differ, but for C++, this is something of a standard. Alternatively, you can simply define the whole function in place of the header declaration, or put everything in a header file.

Comment: @Jon How would I go about doing that? that seems much simpler

Comment: It looks like you are already doing it... you have `getDivisor`, `calcSquare`, and `findNumbers` all neatly declared at the top of your file.. oh, but then you are using them OUTSIDE of the `main` function. That might be your problem, actually. Or... one of your problems.

Comment: @Jon So I should not put `int divisor = getDivisor();` and `int square = calcSquare(divisor);` before main? I think you were right in that being one of my problems, down to 1 unresolved external now.

Comment: Also, as noted in comments from others, there are useless function declaration in `main`, followed by blocks. A quick search for "c++ function definitions vs declarations" turned up the following: [What's the difference between declaring and defining in C and C++](https://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html)

Comment: All the useless declarations have been removed, strange that my teacher taught us to declare before main as well as in main. All edits have been posted, still 1 unresolved external symbol and I am not sure where to define the functions if not outside main

Comment: Well, whichever mysterious external symbol is undefined, that's the one that needs to be defined. The error message speaks for itself. Look for typos in function names.

Comment: I found it! No more errors! Only problem is that nothing displays when i run it, only "Press any key to continue . . ."

Comment: The 3rd line of your program is a return. Execution stops there.  Why so many unnecessary braces?

Comment: I removed them a few minutes  ago, my teacher taught us to include those as well as the function declarations at the top of each block of code. Updated to what I have now if anyone is still trying to help me. My only problem is with my for loop now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a lot of problems with your code, and your edits made them worse.

This is what I think you were trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int getDivisor();
int calcSquare(int divisor);
void findNumbers(int divisor);

int main()
{
    int divisor = getDivisor();
    findNumbers(divisor);
    return 0;
}

int getDivisor()
{
    int divisor = 0;
    cout << "Enter a divisor: ";
    cin >> divisor;
    return divisor;
}

int calcSquare(int divisor)
{
    return divisor * divisor;
}

void findNumbers(int divisor)
{
    cout << "Here are the numbers from 1 to 100 that are evenly divisible by " << divisor << ", and their squares : \n\n";
    for (int count = 1; count <= 100; ++count)
    {
        if (count % divisor == 0)
        {
            cout << count << setw(6) << calcSquare(count) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Putting the function prototypes at the beginning of your program is fine, but you need to understand where and how you implement the functions OUTSIDE of your main function. As you said, this is the second time you've had this problem. I hope this helps you to avoid this issue in the future.

Comment: I really appreciate you, so much. I learn from looking at examples of what the right code is and comparing it to my attempts, not from aggressive yet vague 10 word hints as so many people on here love to give. There is always that knight in shining armor that comes through on this site and today, my noble friend, it was you. The 9 hour battle is over, my brain can rest and my eyes can study the correct code instead of staring at the mess I had on my screen all day. Many blessings and may your future be filled with good fortune.